# Find a function $f$ such that $f$ is harmonic on $D$ and $f|_{\partial D}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, self-learning, harmonic-functions

I understand its solutions in general. But my question is how to decide whether I sould take $Im z^4$ or $Re z^4$? I have two similar examples. And in one example, the real part is taken, but in another example, the imaginary part is taken. Why? And how? Please explain it. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Both the real and imaginery parts of a holomorphic function are harmonic.  It was just a question of which part was convenient for the problem at hand.

Comment: Okay, I just try to learn whether there is a specific reason or not. Thank you. @StevenGubkin